# Disposing SqlConnection in OnActionExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dispose, sqlconnection

Regarding this piece of code:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Fetch some data with db.
        //Maybe call some other private methods that use db.
        return View();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (db != null)
            db.Dispose();

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

1) Can I be sure that db will be disposed, regarding any MVC request life cycle flow (exceptions etc..)
2) Performance wise, are there any issues here ?

(I know there are fancier ways of doing this with inheritance/injection but I am interested in that simple pattern)

Comment: There is some good discussion at these similar answers
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228840/how-to-dispose-of-repository-objects-in-mvc3-controllers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096559/entity-framework-datacontext-concern-is-it-getting-disposed-properly-in-my-con)

Comment: You could also just simply wrap any db calls with a `using(db = new SqlConnection){}` - which will dispose of the object at the end of the statement.